# Php after redirect the button doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, redirect

I have two PHP pages:

**giardino.php**:

```
<?php 
    SESSION_START();
    if (isset($_SESSION['utente'])){    
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
        <head> 

            <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="immagini/favicon.ico"/>

            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>         
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stile.css"/>

        </head> 
        <body> 

            <div data-role="page" data-theme="d">

                <div data-role="header">
                    <a href="ambienti.php" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-l">Ambienti</a>
                    <a href="logout.php" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="delete" >Logout</a>
                    <h1>Domos - Giardino</h1>
                </div><!-- /header -->

                <div data-role="content" id="centramento">

                        <?php
                            include("configurazione.php");
                            $id_stanza=1;
                            $pin=26;
                            //lettura stato attuale
                            $comando="select luci from casa where ID_stanza=1";
                            $query=mysql_query($comando,$connessione);
                            while($riga=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                                $oldstate=$riga['luci'];
                            }       
                            if($oldstate == 0){
                                $newstate='accendi luce';
                                $theme='e';
                            }
                            else{
                                $newstate='spegni luce';
                                $theme='a';
                            }

                            echo "<a href='luce.php' data-role='button' data-theme='$theme' id='radio'>$newstate</a>" 
                        ?>

                </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h4>Credits: Silvio Mattiello 5C Informatica 2014/2015</h4>
            </div><!-- /footer -->

            </div><!-- /page -->

        </body>
    </html>

<?php
    }
    else{
        header("location:home.php?msg=6");
    }
?>
```

**luce.php**:

```
<?php

    $id_stanza=1;
    $pin=$_GET=26;

    $comando = escapeshellcmd("sudo /var/www/domotica/python/luce.py $pin $id_stanza");
    $esito = exec($comando);

    if ($esito == "allarme attivato"){
        header("location:ambienti.php");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        header("location:giardino.php");
        exit();
    }

?>
```

When I click the button on the first page, I get redirected to the second page.
In the second page, there are some operations and then I get redirected to the first page (or another page, **ambienti.php**).
But when I am redirected to the first page again, the button on this page (**giardino.php**) doesn't work. I can't click it. Why?

Comment: `$pin = $_GET = 26`? That just completely trashes your $_GET array and replaces it with an integer.

Answer (score 0):

try to use a require instead of the include, to see if there is any error... It seems to be something with include.

Also, you could try to add 302 http to the header like this and add the full path

```
header('Location: http://server_name/ambienti.php', true, 302);
```